# How to implement search in file system in haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm not exactly new to haskell, but haven't used it much in real world.

So what I want to do is to find all git repositories starting from some folders. Basically I'm trying to do this `find . -type d -exec test -e '{}/.git' ';' -print -prune` only faster via using haskell concurrency features.

This is what I got so far.

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist)
import System.FilePath ((</>))
import System.IO (FilePath)


isGitRepo :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isGitRepo p = doesDirectoryExist $ p </> ".git"


main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello"
```

I've found this [lib](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.14/async-2.1.1/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:mapConcurrently) which has this function `mapConcurrently :: Traversable t => (a -> IO b) -> t a -> IO (t b)`
Which got me thinking that what I need is to produce lazy Tree data structure that would reflect folders structure. Then filter it concurrently with `isGitRepo` and that fold it into list and print it.
Well, of course I know how to make `data FTree = Node String [FTree]` or something like that, but I have questions.
How to produce it concurrently? How to produce absolute path while traversing the tree? Questions like that and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which got me thinking that what I need is to produce lazy Tree data structure that would reflect folders structure.

I'm not sure you need a tree structure for this. You *could* make an intermediate such structure, but you could just as well manage without one. The key thing is you need to have `O(1)` appending (to combine your results). A difference list (like [`dlist`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist)) does this.

> How to produce it concurrently?

You already got that: using `mapConcurrently`!

> How to produce absolute path while traversing the tree?

[`listDirectory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.0.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:listDirectory) lets you get the next possible segments in the path. You can get the next paths by appending each of these segments to the existing path (they won't be absolute paths unless the existing path was though).

---

Here is a working function:

```
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, listDirectory)
import System.FilePath ((</>), combine)
import System.IO (FilePath)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (mapConcurrently)
import qualified Data.DList as DL

-- | tries to find all git repos in the subtree rooted at the path
findGitRepos :: FilePath -> IO (DL.DList FilePath)
findGitRepos p = do
  isNotDir <- not <$> doesDirectoryExist p
  if isNotDir
    then pure DL.empty             -- the path 'p' isn't a directory
    else do
      isGitDir <- doesDirectoryExist (p </> ".git")
      if isGitDir
        then pure (DL.singleton p) -- the folder is a git repo
        else do                    -- recurse to subfolders
          subdirs <- listDirectory p
          repos <- mapConcurrently findGitRepos (combine p `map` subdirs)
          pure (DL.concat repos)
```

Comment: Hey! What if I'd like to print results as they are available? With this It version it will only print the whole list at the end (faster than with find actually, which is good, but still). I can probably create a solution using channels, but maybe there is easier way?

Comment: @user1685095 I guess a channel is probably the way to go... Alternately, you could use something prebuilt for this. A quick search yields https://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-output-1.7.8/docs/System-Console-Concurrent.html