# Nested directories list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm just wondering if I can use any specific method from System.Directory package or something to get a list of all nested directories given a specified path. I have not found any appropriate function so I came up with something like this:

```
getDirList :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getDirList dir = do
  contents <- getDirectoryContents dir
  all <- mapM (return . (dir </>)) $ filter (\f -> f /= "." && f /= "..") contents
  dirs <- filterM doesDirectoryExist all
  dirs' <- mapM getDirList dirs
  return (dir : concat dirs')
```

May be I have been missing something really simple? Can anybody suggest? Thank you.

Comment: [Maybe relevant from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404647/how-to-implement-search-in-file-system-in-haskell).

Comment: Not an answer, but note that you can use `listDirectory` in place of `getDirectoryContents` to automatically filter out the `.` and `..` special directories.

Comment: Yes, I noticed listDirectory. Actually I oversaw that filtering from this function. :) Happy new year.

Comment: The directory package is wrong and dangerous, since it uses a false representation of filepath (String). Look at the [AbstractFilePath](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Proposal/AbstractFilePath) proposal for reasoning. Some packages like [hpath](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpath-0.8.0/docs/System-Posix-Directory-Traversals.html#v:allDirectoryContents) and [posix-paths](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/posix-paths-0.2.1.0/docs/System-Posix-Directory-Traversals.html) (not maintained anymore) have recursive functions for that and use a safe ByteString representation for filepath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok to use [filemanip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/FileManip-0.3.3.1/docs/System-FilePath-Find.html) package:

```
import System.FilePath.Find

getDirList dir = find always (fileType ==? Directory) dir
```